# Delete query while matching sustring in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "MYprojects" and a column named with "Rights".Now i have a following row

```
id =>1

rights => 7,4,34,532,12,32
```

Now i need to delete that row if any of the number-in rights column presents in the following 
value

```
2,4,65,34
```

As you can see 4 is present in the value in the column so i need to delete that row.
Can someone tell me the mysql query or function for this?
It can be done by server side scripting by applying loops but i need an optimized solution
Thanks

Comment: It seemed to me that you might have a "wrong" design in your database. There seems to be a 1-many relation which should be defined by another "rights" table with a foreign key "Myprojects_id" mapping to ID field of MYprojects and a right field as just an integer containing rights (e.g. you will have 6 entries like: 1,7  1,4  1,34  1,532  1,12  1,32  for storing rights 7,4,34,532,12,32 for MYproject 1), then the sql query will be just a huge OR query

Comment: @daghan: Using your proposed structure, the `DELETE` statement could be expressed more efficiently than "a huge OR query" by using the [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator: `DELETE MYprojects FROM MYprojects JOIN rights ON rights.Myprojects_id = MYprojects.id WHERE rights.right IN (2,4,65,34);`.  Note that this approach requires foreign key relations to be defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE` in order to cleanup all records from the `rights` table, which in turn requires use of the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, without InnoDB/foreign key relations, one could join the `rights` table to the `DELETE` query a second time in order to perform the cleanup: `DELETE Myprojects, allrights FROM MYprojects JOIN rights ON rights.Myprojects_id = MYprojects.id JOIN rights AS allrights ON allrights.Myprojects_id = MYprojects.id WHERE rights.right IN (2,4,65,34);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function (which will be particularly efficient if the `Rights` column is stored using the [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) data-type):

```sql
DELETE FROM MYprojects WHERE
     FIND_IN_SET( 2, Rights)
  OR FIND_IN_SET( 4, Rights)
  OR FIND_IN_SET(65, Rights)
  OR FIND_IN_SET(34, Rights)
```

However, as [daghan comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798948/delete-query-while-matching-sustring-in-mysql#comment14048992_10798948), you should probably consider a more suitable datastructure that takes advantage of MySQL's *relational* database management capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `MYprojects` WHERE `rights` REGEXP '(^|,)2($|,)' OR `rights` REGEXP '(^|,)4($|,)' OR `rights` REGEXP '(^|,)65($|,)' OR `rights` REGEXP '(^|,)34($|,)'
```

Is the neatest way I can think of doing it. The regular expression makes sure that the number entered is part of a list, and not just part of another number ('1' doesn't match '11' for example). It does require some looping to construct the query if you're doing it through script, but it's minimal compared to a lot of `SELECT`ing first.